# FFmpeg Auto Level, Auto Color etc similar to YouTube's Auto-Fix

Tags: ffmpeg

I used to use YouTube Auto-Fix which presumably auto fixed levels, color, contrast and added a bit of vibrance (it was almost always a bit high saturated which i kinda liked).

I am looking for an alternate in ffmpeg. I tried using `-vf pp=al` but it only lightens the video.

Any ideas?

P.S. I can do this in Premiere/After Effects but am looking for a ffmpeg solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. Maybe you can check out the [Super User Stack Exchange](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg)